# Adding row in a table with javascript = strange result in Chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I've got to add a new row with it's content populated from an ajax query when I click on any row present. Everything is working well in ie8, ff3.6, opera11, but in chrome10 and safari5 the row are always shown as the first row even if the HTML code is well ordered.

the javascript use is here:

```
jQuery('.tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_cour_line').click(function (){
    if(running==false){
        running=true;
        jQuery('.cour_detail_temp_inner').slideUp(500, function () {
            jQuery(this).parents('.cour_detail_temp').remove();
        });
        var td=jQuery(this).after('<tr class="cour_detail_temp"><td colspan="8" style="padding: 0pt;"><div class="cour_detail_temp_inner" style="display: none;"></div></td></tr>');
        td=td.next().find('.cour_detail_temp_inner');
        var url=jQuery(this).find('.tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_detail_link a').attr('href');

        td.load(url,function(){
            jQuery(this).slideDown(500,function(){running=false;});
        });
    }
});
```

and here is the HTML (it's typo3 template):

```
<table class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_liste" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
    <th>###TITRE_WEB###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_PDF###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_DETAILS###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_SIGLE###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_TITRE###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_ENLIGNE###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_ENSEIGNANT###</th>
    <th>###TITRE_RESPONSABLE###</th>
</tr>

<!-- ###COURS### begin -->
<tr class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_cour_line">
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_link"><!-- ###COURS_LINK### begin -->###COURS_WEB_IMAGE###<!-- ###COURS_LINK### end --></td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_link"><!-- ###PDF_LINK### begin -->###PDF_IMAGE###<!-- ###PDF_LINK### end --></td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_link tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_detail_link"><!-- ###DETAILS_LINK### begin -->###DETAILS_IMAGE###<!-- ###DETAILS_LINK### end --></td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_sigle" nowrap>###COURS_SIGLE###</td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_titre">###COURS_TITRE###</td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_enligne">###COURS_ENLIGNE###</td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_enseignant" nowrap>###COURS_ENSEIGNANT###</td>
    <td class="tx_tacticinfocours_pi1_responsable" nowrap>###COURS_RESPONSABLE###</td>
</tr>
<!-- ###COURS### end -->
```

have you got any idea why it's doing so or any work around?

Comment: Could you also give us the related html please?

Comment: the html is in some template form but i'm adding it in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try turning:
`var td=jQuery(this).after(...)`

to: `var td=jQuery('<tr class="cour_detail_temp"><td colspan="8" style="padding: 0pt;"><div class="cour_detail_temp_inner" style="display: none;"></div></td></tr>').appendTo(this);`

I think what you've got there is more of a css problem than a javascript problem.

Comment: that is actually adding a tr inside the clicked tr which isn't valid AFAIK and with insertAfter I've got the exact same problem. I think it's probably more a webkit problem with inserting row in the middle of a table so it's the rendering engine that I've got to trick...

Comment: The thing is, I've tried it with jsfiddle, and it works fine. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/k68qe/) the slightly modified version. Tested with Chrome 10, and it shows the new table row below the table like advertised.

Comment: yes I just tested it with real data and it really work, one difference: I'm using jquerry 1.5.2 not 1.5.1 I might test that when a return a the office (I cannot access the code right now)

Comment: you where right it's actualy a css problem comming from a display block on a tr...
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this today. Turns out the "main rows" in my table had display:block, which makes the new ones that have display:table-row end up on top even if they're mingled in the HTML. Having display:table-row on the "main rows" leaves the inserted ones in place. Go figure! (Safari only)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the problem, but instead of:

```
var td=jQuery(this).after(...)
```

try this:

```
var td=jQuery(this).parent().after(...)
```

Comment: Doing so is adding a <td> after the <tbody> wich is logical with the code you gave but make no sense in HTML. 
Still thanks